# Feed Forward Neural Network - How to Visualize the Weight Matrix?

Tags: neural-networks, weights

I'm a bit confused about the visualization of the weights of a feed forward neural network as provided in this example [from scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_mnist_filters.html). The network has an architecture of `[784 x 50 x 10]` (MNIST dataset), so `n_hidden = 50` (there are 50 hidden units). Each of the hidden units is a column of the weight matrix `W_1` (with dimension 784x50), right? From this, I thought, we could create `50` images, each of size 28x28 (=784). However, there are only 16 images shown? What is my mistake here?

[image]

**EDIT**

Since someone downvoted the question without explanation, here is what I assume. In the particular example stated above, one could acutally draw 50 pictures. Visualizing only 16 filters (4x4) was choosen for convenience.

Comment: Interesting question. But I have a question for you too: have you run the code yourself too? The author of the article might have chosen to show only 16/50 neurons. So if you didn't run the script yourself: do so!

Comment: @Thomas W, I did and came to the same conclusion as you. Just really thought I misunderstood something and went over and over again. There is a similar example on the theano tutorial side where they just visualized 100/500 neurons without further explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, and there should be `50` images. You could easily verfiy this by:

```
[coef.shape for coef in mlp.coefs_[0]]
```

where `mlp` is the trained MLP classifer in the example.

So here are the two things caused confusion:

- Clearly, the author of the example did not mention anything about why only `16` images
- In Python when you zip two things in the for loop that don't have equal length (number of items) in this example `zip(mlp.coefs_[0].T, axes.ravel())`, Python will automatically ignore the extra items in the bigger lists (arrays, etc.). Here `axes.ravel()` has only **16** items, therefore, the loop iterates over first 16 vectors in mlp.coefs_[0]